# Extract specific text from webpage

Tags: python, web-scraping, text-extraction

May I ask how to extract

- County name
- and answer for confirmed cases, death?

For example: {'Alabama':{'Augauta County':{'confirmed cases':'1522','death':'24'}, 'Baldwin County':{'confirmed cases':'4787','death':'7'}}}, etc

Webpage link https://usafacts.org/visualizations/coronavirus-covid-19-spread-map/state/alabama

I was able to **scrape** and save this webpage as a file.

Thank you so much!

Text 1

```
{"@type":"ImageObject","url":"https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5a1340ef914e6bf3c0764c0c/t/5dbb4885de62ca18968da164/1582662729455/?format=1500w"},"founder":"Steve Ballmer","legalName":"Ballmer Giving LLC"}},"mainEntityOfPage":"/visualizations/coronavirus-covid-19-spread-map"}</script><script data-react-helmet="true" type="application/ld+json">{"@context":"https://schema.org","@type":"FAQPage","mainEntity":[{"@type":"Question","name":"How many COVID-19 cases in Autauga County, Alabama?","acceptedAnswer":{"@type":"Answer","text":1522}},{"@type":"Question","name":"How many COVID-19 cases in Baldwin County, Alabama?","acceptedAnswer":{"@type":"Answer","text":4787}},
```

Text 2

```
{"@type":"Question","name":"How many COVID-19 deaths in Autauga County, Alabama?","acceptedAnswer":{"@type":"Answer","text":24}},{"@type":"Question","name":"How many COVID-19 deaths in Baldwin County, Alabama?","acceptedAnswer":{"@type":"Answer","text":46}},{"@type":"Question","name":"How many COVID-19 deaths in Barbour County, Alabama?","acceptedAnswer":{"@type":"Answer","text":7}}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the text that you extracted is an array of json object, so just simply enclose it with a bracket and load into dict using the json library

something like this?

```
import json

text2 = '''{"@type":"Question","name":"How many COVID-19 deaths in Autauga County, Alabama?","acceptedAnswer":{"@type":"Answer","text":24}},{"@type":"Question","name":"How many COVID-19 deaths in Baldwin County, Alabama?","acceptedAnswer":{"@type":"Answer","text":46}},{"@type":"Question","name":"How many COVID-19 deaths in Barbour County, Alabama?","acceptedAnswer":{"@type":"Answer","text":7}} '''
data = json.loads('[' + text2 + ']')
for item in data:
    print(item['name'])
    print(item['acceptedAnswer']['text'])
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!
But I have a file (downloaded from a webpage)  https://usafacts.org/visualizations/coronavirus-covid-19-spread-map/state/alabama
How can I get those texts like text 1 and text 2 out first? before using json?
@grandia